# How to add click/long click listener to ViewPager2

Tags: java, android

I moved from `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2`. Since there's no way to set a clickable callback to `ViewPager2` or extend it to be clickable, I did this:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewPager2 viewPagerTop;
    ViewPager2Adapter viewPager2TopAdapter;
    ClickableListener topClickableListener;

    public interface ClickableListener {
        public void on(int position);
        public boolean onLong(int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickTop(ClickableListener clickableListener) {
        topClickableListener = clickableListener;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
        viewPagerTop = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerTop);

        viewPagerTop.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d("AAA", "long clicked!");
            int position = viewPagerTop.getCurrentItem();
            return topClickableListener.onLong(position);
        });
        viewPagerTop.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d("AAA", "clicked!");
            int position = viewPagerTop.getCurrentItem();
            topClickableListener.on(position);
        });
```

but it won't work. I see nothing on log.

Comment: Check this. This should work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881654/963038

Answer (score 0):

After initialising the view add this **yourPager.setUserInputEnabled(false);**
I face same issue by adding this line i am able to perform longClickAction on viewPager